# What decides the limit of expeditions that I can send?

Tags: genshin-impact

I could send 2 expeditions at the beginning, then 4, now it's 5. What are the breakpoints that give you the power to send more expeditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of [expeditions](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Expeditions) you can send out is based on your adventure rank, with 5 being the maximum. According to the wiki, the following are when the expeditions limit is increased

| Adventure Rank | Expedition Limit |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 2 |
| 26 | 3 |
| 31 | 4 |
| 36 | 5 |